# how to force a footer to the bottom of a wrapper with overflow:hidden;?

Tags: html, css

I am making webpages with a wrapper with **overflow:hidden;**, a navigation column with **float:left;**, content, and a footer. I added padding to the navigation column so it's background color reach to the end of the wrapper and set the wrapper to **overflow:hidden;** so it will expand match the navigation column. The problem is I can't get the footer to go to the bottom.

css

```
#nav{
    background:skyblue;
    padding:8px 8px 350px 8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;}

#wrapper{
    width:80%;
    min-width:960px;
    background:#90C7E3;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px gray;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;}

#footer{
    font-size:75%;}
```

html

```
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home.html">H</a>
          <li><a href="a.html">A</a>
          <li><a href="b.html">B</a>
          <li><a href="c.html">C</a>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="content">
         <h2>content</h2>     
         <p>contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</p>
       </div>
       <div id="footer">
         <p>footerfooterfooterfooterfooter<br>
         <em>footerfooterfooter</em></p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </body>
```

I'm not sure I posted the code correctly for it's my first time posting on this website.

Answer (score 1):

Use clear:both in footer.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetandoke/w7UfH/)

```
  #footer{
 font-size:75%;
clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-top attribute for footer.
JsFiddle Link here : http://jsfiddle.net/L5REZ/

```
   #footer{
        margin-top:40%;
        font-size:75%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<div id="footer">
  <p>footerfooterfooterfooterfooter<br>
  <em>footerfooterfooter</em></p>
</div>
<br><br>
```

just before the 
`</body>` tag
here is some [JSfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ35Y/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 #footer
{
   font-size:75%;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:80px; /* Need a fixed height */
  position:absolute; /* Sets the position on a set spot */
  bottom:0; /* Tells the footer div to stay at 0 which is the bottom of the page */
}
```

This will push the footer down no matter how far the content goes.

Source: http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Hope this helped! Good luck.